# combine two foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

**first foreach**

```
foreach (range(1, 70) as $num) {
   echo 'Number '.$num.'<br />';
}
```

**second**

```
ksort($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $key => $value){
    echo 'Number '.$key.' = '.$value.' times<br />';
}
```

First Foreach create numbers list from 1 to 70.
Second Foreach take some info from db (**$numbers**) like

```
Number 1 = 1 times
Number 2 = 1 times
Number 6 = 1 times
Number 11 = 1 times
Number 12 = 1 times
Number 13 = 1 times
Number 14 = 1 times
Number 16 = 1 times
Number 17 = 1 times
Number 21 = 2 times
Number 24 = 1 times
Number 25 = 1 times
Number 28 = 1 times
Number 30 = 1 times
Number 31 = 2 times
Number 33 = 1 times
Number 36 = 3 times
Number 38 = 1 times
Number 63 = 1 times
Number 65 = 1 times
```

Now i need do this work like this:

```
if($key==$num){
echo 'Number '.$key.' = '.$value.' times<br />';
}else{
echo 'Number '.$key.' = 0 times<br />';
}
```

All this list from 1 to 70 with show how much times (if exists). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make an associative array for that with the number as key and the value is the number.

```
$numbers = array();
foreach (range(1, 70) as $num)
{
   $numbers[$num] = 0;
}
```

and with the database loop you combine them

```
foreach ($dbnumbers as $num => $value)
{
    $numbers[$num] += $value;
}
```

Then you can just iterate over it for displaying ;)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like you're counting occurrences of numbers.

```
$counter = array();
foreach ($numbers as $num) {
    if (!isset($counter[$num]) {
        $counter[$num] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $counter[$num]++;
    }
}

print_r($counter); # You have all of your occurrences loaded into this tidy array.
```